# Nothing is displayed on the screen when using AnimatedNavHost

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am using Accompanist animation library:

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.24.0-alpha"
```

And I have the following AnimatedNavHost:

```
val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
AnimatedNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "auth",
    enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
    exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }
) {
    composable(
        route = "auth"
    ) {
        AuthScreen(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "profile"
    ) {
        ProfileScreen(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
}
```

My AuthScreen is as simple as:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(bottom = 48.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            signIn()
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = SIGN_IN,
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )
    }
```

When I launch the app nothing is displayed on the screen? No crash. Can anyone help? Thanks

P.S. I'm also using:

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-rc01"
```

I'm using the following imports:

```
import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHost
import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.rememberAnimatedNavController
import androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition
```

Comment: Please include your imports as well

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please check my updated question. I think the AuthScreen(...) isn't called. Any idea? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: You didn't include your import for `composable`. Please just include all of them.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, it was an import problem. I was using `import androidx.navigation.compose.composable` instead of `import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.composable`. THANK YOU so much, you saved me hours. If you want, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per the [Accompanist Navigation Animation migration guide](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/#migration):

> To migrate from using the Navigation Compose APIs do the following:
>
> - Replace `rememberNavController()` with `rememberAnimatedNavController()`
> - Replace `NavHost` with `AnimatedNavHost`
> - Replace `import androidx.navigation.compose.navigation` with import `com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.navigation`
> - **Replace `import androidx.navigation.compose.composable` with import `com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.composable`**

I suspect you haven't actually done the last one - you need to use the Accompanist version of the `composable` NavGraphBuilder extension if you want your destination to be picked up by `AnimatedNavHost`.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Just to update]

> The official androidx.navigation.compose version 2.7.0-alpha01+ offers
> all of the same functionality as Accompanist Navigation Animation.

In your gradle file replace accompanist with official androidx library

```
dependencies{
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7'
    ...
}
```