# How to avoid blank screen when passing startDestination in AnimatedNavHost?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have configured the AnimatedNavHost to have "Dashboard" as the main destination

```
    ProvideNavHostController {
    ProvideNavigate {

        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            AnimatedNavHost(
                navController = LocalNavHost.current,
                startDestination = NavItem.Dashboard.route
            ) {
                ...
            }

            PodcastBottomBar(Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
            PodcastPlayerScreen(backDispatcher)

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I navigate to another screen such as the details screen, and I hit the back button twice, it goes to the previous screen, and a few seconds later it goes back another step. The result is what you can see in the image below.

[image]

As a bonus, here are the versions of the browser dependencies I am using:

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3")
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.27.1")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
```

How could this behaviour be avoided?

Comment: Why does your `PodcastPlayerScreen` take a `backDispatcher`? The `AnimatedNavHost` is already handling the system back button correctly for you and cannot ever get into this scenario with that default behavior.

Comment: PodcastPlayerScreen appears only if the playback bar is pressed, which in this case would be PodcastBottomBar, PodcastPlayerScreen is a full screen showing playback, and the OnBackPressedDispatcher is simply used to control that if it is pressed the full screen of the player is closed, this screen is overridden but should never affect it to the point of going black. In fact, the situation I have mentioned is unrelated. Since from the initial screen, when accessing the details screen and pressing twice back, it makes it go black.

Comment: I have tested this behaviour in another app that I have that only has the providers and AnimatedNavHost and it happens the same way

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug against Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) with a project that reproduces your issue, since this doesn't happen to anyone else, nor does it happen in any of the sample apps that use AnimatedNavHost.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really wanted to ask here first, just in case someone else had this problem, I leave here the link to the issue in case they manage to solve it so that people can know the reason: https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1408

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing is displayed on the screen when using AnimatedNavHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834847/nothing-is-displayed-on-the-screen-when-using-animatednavhost)